# Error in thenComparing in a Comparator java 8

Tags: java, comparator

```java
solicitudes = solicitudes.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> {
        Date fecha = null;
        try {
            fecha = ((CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO) t).getFechaSolicitudToDate();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return fecha;
    })
    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); //FAIL HERE
```

The error Java's throwing when I'm doing `thenComparing` is this:

> The method thenComparing(Comparator<? super Object>) in the type
> Comparator is not applicable for the arguments
> (Comparator<Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>>)

Do you know what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because *type inference* can't resolve it.

Explicitly stating the generic type for the method call usually fixes it for me:

```
Comparator.<Date>comparing(...)
    .thenComparing(...)
```

Comment: Too bad, try "extra variable" in your IDE of each call to the Comparator chained methods to see what type it resolves to.